# Black height of a node

Tags: red-black-tree

In a red-black tree, can the black height between 2 children of a node be greater than 1? In other terms: Suppose x is the root of an RB tree. Can the black height of x.left and x.right differ by more than one?

Answer (score 0):

The black height can't even differ by one. In a properly formed RB tree all leaf nodes are at the same depth. It doesn't matter if the node you are starting from is not the ultimate root, all leaf nodes of that particular node will be at the same depth from the given node.

Answer (score 0):

What SoronelHaetir said is right.

But say the BlackTree height is 10 from the root.
Then you could have a path that is 10 black nodes consecutively. So 10 nodes from root to a real leaf node could be all black nodes.

But a different path from the root  node to a leaf node could be 20 nodes. Why? Because it would be Black-Red-Black-Red etc with last node as Red. There are still 10 Black nodes in the path. But the Red nodes act as fillers.

Whatever the black path count is (say N), the minimum count of nodes from Root to real Leaf node is N and the maximum is 2 * N.